# Does Ubuntu support Mobile IPv6?

Tags: ipv6

I have a network running IPv6 connected to the internet through a router running Ubuntu Server 14.04. My laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 can connect to this network using either Ethernet or WiFi which both work as intended.

Occasionally the laptop is connected to other networks where I would like it to still use the IP address it has from its home network. Mobility Support in IPv6 as defined in [RFC 6275](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6275) (formerly RFC 3775) sounds like the way to achieve that.

Is that protocol supported by Ubuntu?

I have used `apt-cache search` to look for packages mentioning mobility or either RFC number, but found nothing relevant. And I have searched this site as well and found no earlier questions about IPv6 mobility support.